# Calls to Open3D ViewControl seemingly have no effect on visualization yet calls to render options do?

Tags: python, open3d

I my short code example:

```
import numpy as np
import open3d as o3d

points_x = np.random.uniform(0, 1, (100, 3))
points_x[:, 1:] = 0
points_y = np.random.uniform(0, 1, (100, 3))
points_y[:, [0, 2]] = 0
points_z = np.random.uniform(0, 1, (100, 3))
points_z[:, :2] = 0

colors_x = np.zeros((100, 3))
colors_x[:, 0] = 1.0
colors_y = np.zeros((100, 3))
colors_y[:, 1] = 1.0
colors_z = np.zeros((100, 3))
colors_z[:, 2] = 1.0

points = np.concatenate((points_x, points_y, points_z), axis=0)
label_colors = np.concatenate((colors_x, colors_y, colors_z), axis=0)

# Create the point cloud object
pcd = o3d.geometry.PointCloud()
pcd.points = o3d.utility.Vector3dVector(points)
pcd.colors = o3d.utility.Vector3dVector(label_colors)

# Create visualizer object
vis = o3d.visualization.Visualizer()
vis.create_window()

# Add point cloud to the visualizer
vis.add_geometry(pcd)

# Set the point size
ro = vis.get_render_option()
ro.point_size = 2

# Try to alter the camera view
ctr = vis.get_view_control()
ctr.set_front([0, 0, 1])
ctr.set_up([1, 0, 0])
ctr.set_zoom(1.5)

# Run the visualization
vis.run()

# Clean up
vis.destroy_window()
```

I have been attempting to display a point cloud and set a specific viewing geometry of the cloud. I have tried many ways of getting and calling various functions of the `ViewControl`/`Visualizer.get_view_control` to do so. Though, none seem to have any effect. Interestingly, `get_render_option().point_size` does have an effect.

Why aren't my calls to `ViewControl` having an effect?

Answer (score 0):

Did you use the `open3d version==0.17.0`?

I replaced `open3d` version `0.17.0` with `0.16.0` and `ctr` worked!

Command:

```
pip install open3d==0.16.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I am also trying to visualize the point cloud. I am using open3d 0.13.0. my visualizer is setting up like this:

```
vis = o3d.visualization.Visualizer()

vis.create_window(width=2000, height=2000)
vis.get_render_option().point_size = 1 
vis.add_geometry(pcd)

view_control = vis.get_view_control()

view_control.set_front([0.4699189535486108, -0.62764022425775134, 0.62068021233921933])  
view_control.set_lookat([ -0.97243714332580566, -0.1751408576965332, 0.51464511454105377 ])        
view_control.set_up([ -0.36828927493940194, 0.49961995188329117, 0.78405542766104697 ])            
view_control.set_zoom(0.15999999999999961)  

vis.run()
vis.destroy_window()
```

It works well as configured, viewing from angled up direction

Answer (score 0):

Downgrade Version from 0.17.0 to open3d==0.16.0  doesn't help. And also version 0.16.0 have some bug. For example if you call: `view_control = vis.get_view_control()`

like on code above it work properly only first time, second call give this error:
[Open3D WARNING] GLFW Error: The GLFW library is not initialized, and after that you need to restart your kernel or App.

I do trick like on code below:

```
def custom_draw_geometry_with_custom_fov(pcd_in, x=0, y=0, z=0, osi=False):
    pcd = copy.deepcopy(pcd_in)
    angel_x = angel_y = angel_z = 0
    if x != 0:
        angel_x = np.pi / (180 / x)
    if y != 0:
        angel_y = np.pi / (180 / y)
    if z != 0:
        angel_z = np.pi / (180 / z)
    
    R = pcd.get_rotation_matrix_from_xyz((angel_x, angel_y, angel_z))
    pcd.rotate(R, center=(pcd.get_center())) # rotated cloud
    vis = o3d.visualization.Visualizer()
    vis.create_window()
    vis.add_geometry(pcd)
    if osi:
        osi = o3d.geometry.TriangleMesh.create_coordinate_frame(size=50, origin=[-50., 0., 0])
        osi.rotate(R, center=(pcd.get_center()))
        vis.add_geometry(osi)
    vis.update_geometry(pcd)
    vis.update_renderer()
    vis.run()
    vis.destroy_window()
```